# SQL query cleanup - and/or based on condition

Tags: sql, where-clause, code-cleanup

What I'm trying to do is write a query which, based on a boolean will select rows which satisfy two conditions or at least one of the two.

The following is a simplified query that gets the job done. Thing is, the where clause in my query is much more complex so I'm looking for a way to rewrite it in a more readable fashion.

Is this possible?

```
declare @AndParam bit
set @AndParam = 1

SELECT * FROM Table

  Where 
  (@AndParam = 1
  AND
  (Table.CategoryID = 3 
  AND
  Table.Age < 30))

  OR

  (@AndParam = 0
  AND
  (Table.CategoryID = 3 
  OR
  Table.Age < 30))
```

**EDIT:**
This question really is about readability and esthetics.
In the stead of `Table.Age < 30` there are five additional checks including subqueries.  Practically, this means that I have a large section of the code duplicated with only one difference; The **And/Or**.
Seeing as how SQL can be difficult to read I'm looking to fix it up.

Comment: In my opinion, this is the minimal set of clauses and can't be reduced any further. If `@AndParam` is boolean, you could write `@AndParam` and `NOT @AndParam`. But that's just syntactical sugar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
Where
   CASE WHEN Table.CategoryID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
   CASE WHEN Table.Age < 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END -- + more CASEs for each condition
   >=
      CASE WHEN @AndParam = 1 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
      --For more conditions, change 2 above to however many conditions there are
```

You basically make each condition give you a 1 or 0, and then add all of these up - then you do a final check, depending on `@AndParam` on whether you hit the total number of conditions or just at least 1.